# How do I get my STM32 F411 discovery to communicate via UART using the onboard stlink?

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery, st-link

I have installed the latest version of ST link driver. I cant see any ST COM port in the device manager. I am kinda confused on how to do this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCNmP.png)

Comment: What did you do so far? Did you init any UART ports?

Comment: Check the user manuel and schematics of your discovery board. You should find all information you need. For example in UM2153 (STM32L4 IOT board) chapter 7.10

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.